# X-Forwarded-Proto with multiple proxies

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http-headers

I am unable to redirect HTTP to HTTPS using Apache due to us having more than one proxy in between the client and the server.

HTTPS is being terminated on an internet facing load balancer, all other devices (including the Apache server serving the requests) are using HTTP.

I can see that all Apache looks at is the X-Forwarded-Proto of the last proxy in the chain, which is HTTP.

How can I force it to look at the real X-Forwarded-Proto header (of the remote client)?

Comment: Fix the intermediate proxies.

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately, the last intermediate proxy is an Elastic Load Balancer (AWS) - there's nothing relevant to configure. The problem seems to be similar to how all the X-Fowrarded-For IP addresses are chained (i.e. when you view them in Apache logs they show as 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8, 1.3.5.7). We use mod_remoteip to get real client addresses - I was hoping there would be something similar to get the real connection protocol being used by the client?

Comment: To make matters worse, there is two elastic load balancers and a security appliance - the appliance is sandwiched between the two elastic load balancers.

Comment: It sounds like something is terribly wrong with your design, and you need to simplify it.

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately this is built as per the design requirements provided by Sophos (https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/122742). We have an autoscaled set of UTM's and an autoscaled set of backend instances - this is why we have two elastic load balancers. Assuming there is no other option relating to the X-Forwarded-Proto, does that leave us needing to configure HTTPS on all devices including the backend server?

Comment: Probably so, especially if you can't change their stuff.

Comment: You cannot configure it on ELB. Try new ALB, I'm not sure if there is any improvement but try it. Welcome in limitation of "awesomeness of cloud"

Answer (score 0):

For redirections coming from the http backend the only directive you should be concerned about in the reverse proxy is:

```
ProxyPassReverse
```

If a redirection comes from a chain of reverse proxied backends, no matter what they send, if you had a ProxyPassReverse directive in place for any internal name, Apache will change the host in the Location and the scheme (http/s) as the client sent it originally.

The good thing is ProxyPassReverse can be specified as many times as necessary.

So for example, if your reverse proxy hosts the public https://main.example.com and you have a miriad of backends behind sending you redirects like:

```
Location: http://something.example.com/somesome
Location: http://otherthing.internal.example.com/heresomething/jkjljl.whatever
Location: http://deepdowninthechain.some.exampe.com/therethere/there/there
```

All you have to do is add:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://something.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://otherthing.internal.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://deepdowninthechain.some.exampe.com/
```

And Apache HTTPD will return all those Location headers to what the original client requested: https://main.example.com/whatever...